# Do the transpose operator and the adjoint operator have same ranges and kernels?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, transpose

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on a comlex Hilbert space $H$.
Do we have :

$R(A^t)=R(A^*)$

And

$Ker(A^t)=Ker(A^*)$
?

Thank you!

Comment: Another way approach this is to ask if $S$ is a subspace, is $S=\bar{S}$? The answer, in general, is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&i\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then
$$
R(A^*)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\ -ix\end{bmatrix}:\ x\in\mathbb C\right\},
$$
while
$$
R(A^t)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\ ix\end{bmatrix}:\ x\in\mathbb C\right\}.
$$
You can see that they are not the same, since $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ i\end{bmatrix}$ is in $R(A^t)$ but not in $R(A^*)$.

For the kernels, both $A^t$ and $A^*$ give a counterexample.